# can any one help me on below code it's not working on IE?

Tags: jquery

its working on all browsers except IE. I am loading the page within a div by current li value.

```
<ul>    
<li>HOME</li>
<li>GALLARY</li>
<li>FAQ</li>
<li>CONTACT</li>
</ul>

<div class="result"></div>

$('.result').load( $(this).text() + '.html') is not working in IE.


$('ul li').click( function (){
    $('ul li').css({background: "#333", color: "white"});
    $(this).css({background: "red", color: "white"});       
    var dataShow = $(this).text();
    $('.result').load( dataShow + '.html');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Define 'not working'. What exactly is not?

Comment: Which IE version are you testing for?

Comment: Instead of `background`, try `backgroundColor`. But it's a total guess, esp. since you haven't said how this isn't working.

Comment: $('.result').load( dataShow + '.html') not loading on IE 6/7 however it's working fine in FF and safari. i don't know .load it supported in ie or not..please help

Comment: We don't add "solved" to the title of questions when an answer has been accepted. You clicked the "check mark" that marks the answer; that was the proper thing to do.

Comment: @Andrew Barber looks like you are tracking me with a sharp teeth... :) ...any way got the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for IE. see below what i have done. I dont know if its a right way of doing it but it worked for me.

```
    $('ul li').click( function (){
    $('ul li').css({background: "#333", color: "white"});
    $(this).css({background: "red", color: "white"});       
    var url = $.trim($(this).html()) + '.html';
    $('.result').load(url);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please give us more detail, i just tried this by myself, it works well, check this out: [Possible solution](http://jsfiddle.net/jaiwo99/JR39j/1/). But if you are trying to do something like

```
$('result').load('http://www.example.com/index.html');
```

it won't work because of Cross-Site-Scripting

Comment: <ul id="nav"><li>HOME</li><li>GALLARY</li><li>FAQ</li><li>CONTACT</li></ul> here is my navigation and when li clicked i am loading the home.html, gallary.html, faq.html and contact.html within the <div class="result"></div> repectively thorugh var dataShow = $(this).text();
$('.result').load( dataShow + '.html');

Comment: Let me know if i am still now clear about my question. Sorry if i have not explained my question properly i am very new to this blog.

Comment: I have just rephrased my question above.